# Html tags in attr binding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am using following code:

```
<i class="icon-info-sign pull-right" data-toggle='tooltip' data-bind="attr: { 'data-original-title': accessString}"></i>
```

The accessString has html tags in it like `<br />`. but they are getting rendered as it it. That is, `<br />` is not rendered as line break but as text.

Comment: Try to add another attribute `data-html="true"`

Comment: That works. Thank you. Please add it as answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add attribute `data-html="true"` to your `<i>` tag, that will do the trick.